# Correct practice for querying groups in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to understand groups in Firebase database. I've created a simple index called "genres" which I've placed inside my stations node:

```
"STATIONS": {
    "GENRES": {
        "D&B": {
            "RODR": false
        },
        "HipHop": {
            "RODR": false
        },
        "TRANCE": {
            "RODR": true
        }
    },
    "RODR": {
        "PROMOTED": false,
        "downvote": 2,
        "image": "image url",
        "station": "Revolution Of Dance Radio",
        "tag": "We Are The Revolution",
        "upvote": 1001,
        "url": "to be added"
    },
    "UKNRADIO": {
        "Promoted": false,
        "downvote": 2,
        "image": "url for image",
        "station": "UKN RADIO",
        "tag": "The Home Of The Mashup",
        "upvote": 1001,
        "url": "to add"
    }
},
```

Then I have these children in a separate node with the key set to the same as the index key.

How do I query the genre node to get all items in the trance index? Which in this example would be RODR?

### Edit

This value is to gain access to the right child with in my Genres node:

```
String value = getArguments().getString("Genre");
    Log.i("Genre_bundle",value);
```

This is the basic code for showing my list:

```
String DATABASE_CHILD = "STATIONS";
    ref = db.getReference().child(DATABASE_CHILD);
```

### Edit 2

I've tried setting up the query in a separate listener to get the key I need; this works, but only if there's a single item in the node. As soon as I add a second, for example `uknradio= true` it won't show.

```
 String DATABASE_CHILD = "STATIONS";
    ref = db.getReference().child(DATABASE_CHILD).child("GENRES").child(value);

    Query query = ref.orderByValue().equalTo(true);

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren())
                KEYS = dataSnapshot.getKey();

                Log.i("KEY", KEYS);
                getStations(KEYS);
                

        }

 private void getStations(String Key) {
    String DATABASE_CHILD = "STATIONS";
    ref1 = db.getReference().child(DATABASE_CHILD);
    ref1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key_Checker = snap.getKey();

                if (KEYS.matches(key_Checker)) {
                    Log.i("KEY", "Present");
```

Comment: My initial guess is that you're looking for a [client-side join](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+client-side+join). Can you edit your question to replace two JSON snippets with a single JSON snippet showing both. This may help us understand how the two are related, and what the problem is in loading them.

Comment: Please provide what Frank van Puffelen asked for, so it can be easy for us to help.

Comment: just doing this now cheers guys :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can u check my edited post thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for that update. From what you're now showing, the `snapshot` in `onDataChange` should be getting all data that is under `STATIONS` in your JSON. Given that: what line of your code isn't doing what you expect it to do? Or alternatively: what output are you looking to generate (`Log.i()` type output always preferred over UI elements that we can't see). Oh, and no - it is unlikely that this has anything to do with an `.index` in your rules as you're not performing any query in the code you shared.

Comment: added the query to the code sorry dont know why that wasnt there.. im sure this is the bit im getting wrong though as im querying one node and the items im querying are in a seperate node. the key is the only thing in my "GENRES" node. cheers for getting back to me though

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can u check my new edit please i have tried to set up a second listener to gain they key i need but its only fetching 1 so if add more it does not show them. cheers for the help and not getting to frustrated with me x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read the stations for the `TRANCE` genre, that's a two-step process:

1. Read the `/STATIONS/GENRES/TRANCE` path to get the keys of the stations.
2. Loop over the keys and read each station's info in turn.

In code with hardcoded values that'd loop like:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference genreRef = rootRef.child("STATIONS/GENRES/TRANCE");
genreRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot genreSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot stationKeySnapshot: genreSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String stationKey = stationKeySnapshot.getKey();

            DatabaseReference stationRef = rootRef.child("STATIONS").child(stationKey);
            stationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot stationSnapshot) {
                    Log.i("DB", stationSnapshot.child("station").getValue(String.class);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this frank this was exactly what i was trying to achieve